# Why aren't my captions working properly when I try to condense 2 CSS rule-sets into one?

Tags: html, css, image

So, I am just starting to make my fist web page with HTML, CSS and JS, and I want a black semi-opaque square over an image, with text inside.

In the CSS, I have a rule-set that I am having trouble with: ".caption". This class is a div's class, and you'll see that there are 2 rule sets commented out.

Thing is, when I uncomment them, and comment the ".caption", the page works perfectly. But when commented the  way below, it doesn't work at all, the text appears under the image, with no formatting.

I know I don't have to change it, but I want to, to target both text elements at once,and for the grey box around them to be a square, not a 5 sided shape(links below for images) and cleaner code.
Is there a way? The text is in its own class and div, right?

This is the code:

```css
.teamworkImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}


/*.caption h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

.caption p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 360px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding: 10px;*/
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id = 'main'>    
    <div class = 'image'>    
        <img src = 'img/teamwork.jpg'
         class = 'teamworkImage'>    
        <div class = 'caption'>
            <h1>THIS IS TEAMWORK</h1>
            <p>
                Our team-building activites help you form new friends, face fears, and - most important of all - have fun.
            </p>
        </div>   
    </div>    
</div>
```

With the CSS code below
[image]

with the commented parts of the CSS un-commented and the '.caption' rule set commented
[image]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pq85z3um/)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, what do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: You can try specific width and height for .caption class

Comment: Chris W. As I said, I wanted to put both rule-sets into one, and for the grey box to be a 4-sided square, not a 5 sided shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the closing curly-brace for `.caption p` that is left outside the comment. This breaks the css at this point, so `.caption` is never evaluated and applied.

I added a placeholder image in the snippet below and centered the `caption` on the image, with the updated comment just for example.

Also, you should be sure to set `position: relative` on the element to which absolute elements are relative to, otherwise, it may end up being relative to the body.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
}
.teamworkImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}


/*.caption h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

.caption p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 360px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding: 10px; BEFORE THE CLOSE COMMENT WAS HERE!!!
}*/

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'main'>    
    <div class='image'>    
        <img src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/ccee00/ffffff'
         class = 'teamworkImage'>    
        <div class='caption'>
            <h1>THIS IS TEAMWORK</h1>
            <p>
                Our team-building activites help you form new friends, face fears, and - most important of all - have fun.
            </p>
        </div>   
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Yours worked a charm! I'm blind at times! What is 'TranslateY'?

Comment: `translateY` is a transform function that moves an element along the Y-axis, which is a 2D environment is vertical. Combining this with `top:50%` is a CSS trick for centering something vertically. So, if you like my answer, be sure to accept it so others won't need to provide an answer.

Comment: Of course. Yours _did_ work how I wished. In fact, better!

Answer (score 0):

The primary trouble is that you have a bunch of things positioned aboslutely. That's dangerous and should be used sparingly. Also, be deliberate about what element you're positioning absolutely inside of. That element must not have static (default) positioning itself.

```css
.image {
  position: relative; /* <-- set an ancestor as the container */
}
.image > img {
  width: 100%;
}
.caption h1 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 60px;
}

.caption p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute; /* <-- just this box is absolutely-positioned */
  bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div class='image'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/800x500' class='teamworkImage'>
    <div class='caption'>
      <h1>THIS IS TEAMWORK</h1>
      <p>
        Our team-building activites help you form new friends, face fears, and - most important of all - have fun.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when i use relative, there is still empty space where the element was originally, so I used absolute, so the container disappears. Any workaround etc?